# PHP messes up <script> in the .tpl header

Tags: php, jquery

I am writing some php code that creates pages from tpl files, which works just fine. However, I have decided to include some funky jquery stuff using the jqueryui engine and I can't get it to work. In the header.tpl, I have the following

```
<script src="...."></script>
<script>
$(function() {
// a workaround for a flaw in the demo system (http://dev.jqueryui.com/ticket/4375), ignore!
$( "#dialog:ui-dialog" ).dialog( "destroy" );
$("#dialog-message").dialog({ autoOpen: false })
$( "#dialog-message" ).dialog({
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            Ok: function() {
        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
    }
});     
$("#tac").click(function() {
    $( "#dialog-message" ).dialog('open');
    // prevent the default action, e.g., following a link
    return false;
}); 
});
</script>
```

This code produces the desired effect when I test it in a plain html page. However, when the page is produced by the php code, it just doesn't. Besides, when I view source on this php-generated page, this is what I get in the header

```
<script>
$(function() )

    $( "#dialog-message" ).dialog(
        }
    });

    $("#tac").click(function() );

});
</script>
```

PHP seems to destroy most of the code and I can't understand why it happens. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Guys, thanks very much for your help! Your comments led me in the right direction and I figured it out. The culprit was my "preg_match" statement in the template engine, which I put right. Now everything works. Thanks again!

Comment: just noticed that the preg_replace stopped working on the tpl elements, which I define as {element}. The preg_replace is 
          
$this->content = preg_replace ('#{nbd_(.+?)}#si', '', $this->content);

Any idea how I should state it so that it recognizes the {template_bit} and does not destroy the javascript in the header? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Since you haven't shown any PHP code or told us how the backend works, I have to guess. It really seems as if you are using Smarty or any other similar template engine. Had the same issue when I started using it.

Have a look at this [documentation](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.literal.tpl)

So, do it this way:

```
{literal}
    // your javascript code
{/literal}
```

Answer (score 1):

try doing

```
<script type="text/javascript">...</script>.
```

And make sure your

```
<scripts />
```

arn't wrapped around any

```
<?php ?>
```

tags